# Clarification on script authorization

Tags: google-apps-script

I realize when a script originates from within a spreadsheet, it needs the user to run the script once (from within the spreadsheet) to authorize then again to execute.

1) So you should never deploy a stand-along UI app (that originates from a spreadsheet) if it needs authorization and you have it executing as the user, correct?

2) Was this a big point of launching script.google.com - so that you can run scripts as the user when stand-along UI apps need authorization first?

3) If the second question is true, then I'm assuming that all stand-along UI apps that would be listed in the chrome store would need to originate from script.google.com?

Comment: I really don't understand your questions fully and you intimate there's a downside somewhere. It would help me possibly answer if you described an example of a reproducible set of events, what you see and what you expected to see.

Comment: Ok, so my questions came about when I was trying to authorize a script  (from a spreadsheet) as an effective user and it wouldn't leave the authorization screen.  I took the same code and pasted it into a new script on script.google.com and it let the authorization through under that same user.  So, I'm tying to figure out the reasons why an effective user can't get past the authorization screen even after clicking ok to authorize.

Comment: The script url that is experiencing this - https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwQ1NUoC_YAqcDn2lO4Pw-PXI6N3OtoODzaKz4ISxXplYVo9xku/exec

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first point is no... and so the next 2 questions (which aren't real questions but rather opinions ) become pointless.
..
To be more accurate, standalone apps just need to be authorized by the user the first time they are called by their URL, that's it...

Comment: Ok, what would be some reasons why an effective user can't get past the authorization screen in a standalone app?

Comment: I see in another of your comments :'it wouldn't leave the authorization screen' what does this mean actually ? what was going on? was the user logged in?

Comment: Yes user logged in (me on another acct). Then I go to the script url and see the auth screen - https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3JTymuE8awLend4UnhpeVFaZlE. I can click the Authorize link and it will send a confirmation email each time I do, but that screen doesn't go away.

Comment: Indeed, I tested your link, I did receive an email telling me that I granted access to your script but that's all. this is not a normal behaviour. without knowing what is in this script I can't have any idea.

Comment: Well, I tried to restore the exact code (to post here) as I have saved over it since, but it was saved on another .gs file within the same script.  Can you restore other .gs files from the revision history or is the Code.gs the only file able to be restored?

Comment: good question... I guess each gs file has its own revision history, it would be logical... but I've never been in that exact situation, I always keep the same gs file along development...

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of where a script resides - spreadsheet or standalone, the 'effective user' (user under whose authority the script eventually runs) needs to authorize it.

The difference now (after IO 2012) is that standalone apps can be run under the credentials of the active user (active user = effective user).

The active user still has to authorize the script to do so. 
I recommend you install Drive Eye from the Chrome Web Store and you'll see what I'm saying first hand.

Comment: Yeah I tried Drive Eye and it worked for me (although recently I've been getting email notifications saying it has failed).  I put the script I was using up top